# How to prevent access to my website by IP?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, ip

I read in other similar questions that I cannot prevent access by IP. I have an apache server that serves several Virtual Hosts, but unfortunately every time I access by IP it redirects me to the first virtual host. How can I generate an error that disables IP access to the site? I have seen many hosting providers do it.

Comment: Show us the config that's not working. You likely need a default virtualhost.

Comment: Apache generally uses the first virtualhost it finds as a 'default'.  If you use the ''file per vhost' approach, a common solution is to create a file called something like 000-default.conf', which get's read first, and you stick your default actions in there.

Comment: @KHobbits Ready, in this case, what would the servername be or is it optional?

Comment: It is optional.